# How to response with text/xml media type in ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, json, asp.net-web-api

Here is my api action:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    string foo = GetXmlString();
    return Ok(foo);
}
```

I wish the response can return "`text/xml`" type when the related request happens. If I do nothing (use default configuration), the return type would be "`application/xml`", if I did following configuration:

```
var applicationXml = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.MediaType == "application/xml");
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(applicationXml);
var textXml = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.MediaType == "text/xml");
if (textXml == null)
{
    config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml"));
}
```

It would use "`application/json`" instead. But I don't want to remove "`application/json`", which is the default media type.

And why the action level config cannot be applied as expected, but use the global one? I am quite confused with this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using config file

Add this in `WebApiConfig`:

```
config.Formatters.Clear();
config.Formatters.Add(new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
// config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
// config.Formatters.Add(new FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this specific request to return with a specific "Content-Type", you can use [`Request.CreateResponse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.createresponse(v=vs.118).aspx) and pass in the formatter you desire:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, new StringContent(""),
                              new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
```

You may also want to review [this post](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation) about content negotiation in WebAPI

Answer (score 0):

You can try these:

**01**

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, new StringContent(""),
                              new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
```

**02**

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, new StringContent(""),
                              new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml"));
```

**03**

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, new StringContent(""),
                              Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```